# Should the "correct" answer with mistake be accepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If the fact is

> Nancy is a cat, Mancy is a dog.

and I asked a question

> Is Nancy a cat?"

Suppose someone else answers

> Yes, Nancy is a cat while Mancy is an octopus.

It correctly answers the question but somehow mentions something wrong, I feel strange to accept it, but writing myself a new answer also seems a bit strange, as the "Nancy is a cat" part is just a complete copy of his.

What should I do in this situation? Write a comment below the answer and waiting for the answerer to fix so I could accept?

Comment: It is not required for an asker to accept an answer. Though, you ought to if the answer helps. You can even come after months to accept an answer. About the latter part, someone will come along and correct it by commenting on it. That's why it is recommended to wait for at least 24h or more.

Comment: I think it's the reason why there is an editing other people's post feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally.

So, it's up to you, really. Accept it if you wish, or ask for extraneous/misleading information to be removed/corrected. Alternatively, leave the answer as 'unaccepted'. Perhaps a better one will be written. Whatever you do, it is better not to accept answers immediately. Wait for 24 hours before doing so is the usual advice.